# Python: print unicode char escaped

Tags: python, unicode

I have tried to convert an ascii string to an escaped pseudo unicode escaped string using python, but failed so far.

What I want to do: Convert ASCII 'a' to ASCII String "`<U0061>`"

I can convert "a" with unicode('a'), but can not safe the numerical value of a in an ascii string.

How can I do that?

Comment: What I want to do: Convert ASCII 'a' to ASCII String "U+0061"

Comment: What if it's outside the BMP?

Comment: Why is the BMP relevant?  A code point is a code point. Doesn't python have abstract characters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `ord()` to convert a character to its character value (`str`) or code point (`unicode`). You can then use the appropriate string formatting to convert it into a text representation.

```
'U+%04X' % (ord(u'A'),)
```

Comment: This fails: ` 'U+%04X' % (ord(u'\U000010eeb'),)`.  But in Perl, `printf "U+%05X\n", ord(chr(0x10eebA))` correctly prints the expected  `U+10EEBA`.  What’s wrong with Python’s model of strings and/or characters? Something seems broken here.

Comment: @tchrist, do you have a wide or narrow python build? Unicode character in narrow build (typical on Windows) is limited to 0-0xffff range.

Comment: @Constantine, apparently I have a “narrow build” — whatever that means. I’m on an Apple, not a Microsoft box. How do you write portable Python if you are forced to always think about characters’ physical layouts in the various encodings? I just want to process a UTF-8 stream, no matter whether characters are ASCII, in the BMP, in the SMP, or anywhere else. How come Unicode characters aren’t just Unicode characters? Why is it possible to build Python so it cannot handle Unicode correctly?

Comment: @tchrist: If you have a UCS-2 build then characters above the BMP are indicated by a surrogate pair, which is actually two UCS-2 characters acting as a single Unicode codepoint.

Comment: @Ignacio Vázquez-Abrams: I finally figured that out. It’s an ugly scenario, one I’m painfully familiar with due to JBD (Java Brain Damage). I had really hoped Python gave abstract characters “that just work”, the way Perl’s do. We’ve been post-BMP in the Unicode space since last millennium, so I cannot believe that all these languages are still suffering so badly for dealing with ÜberBMP characters. ***ALAS AND ALACK!***

Comment: @tchrist: If you have a UCS-4 build then it works as expected. The problem is that most people do not use characters outside the BMP so they complain about the doubled memory usage.

Comment: @Ignacio Vázquez-Abrams: The main problem I see with UCS-4 builds is that you can’t distribute programs that rely on that, but you need it for full Unicode support. If the memory consumption is such a trauma, wouldn’t it have been better to use UTF-8 for an internal representation? That’s quite small for any “Western” language. I realize its shortcoming in direct-addressability, but besides being svelte, it’s also automatically extensible above the BMP. Any insight why this hasn’t yet been done? *Could* it be?  Thanks very much.

Comment: @tchrist: No program should ever have to rely on a specific build in that manner, and if they do then they're Doing It Wrong. The lack of direct-addressability in UTF-8 is a *huge* shortcoming, since it means that string operations can be *very* slow.

Comment: @tchrist, It is well-documented that perl utf8 string manipulations have inferior performance, see "Speed" section of http://search.cpan.org/~jhi/perl-5.8.0/pod/perlunicode.pod. It recommends converting utf8 strings to arrays of characters to avoid orders of magnitude slowdown. Looks like Perl and Python implementers just picked different sets of trade-offs.

Comment: @Constantin: If I had to choose between fast and correct, I’d choose correct every time. After all, if it doesn’t have to be correct, I can any bit of code arbitrarily fast.

Comment: @tchrist, that is only sensible if correctness is viewed as a value with discrete {True, False} domain instead of continuous [0, 1].

Answer (score 1):

Here goes a minimalist sample that allows you to use Ignacio's solution with Python's built-in coding/decoding engine. Check http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html if you need something more consistent (with proper error handling, etc...)

```
import codecs


def  encode(text, error="strict"):
    return ("".join("<U%04x>" % ord(char) for char in text), len(text))

def search(name):
    if name == "unicode_ltgt":
        info = codecs.CodecInfo(encode, None, None, None)
        info.name = "unicode_ltgt"
        info.encode = encode
        return info
    return None

codecs.register(search)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = u"maçã"
    print a.encode("unicode_ltgt")
```

(just by importing this as a module, the codec "unicode_ltgt" will be installed and be available to any ".encode" call, like in the given example )